# How to organise Javascript functions within complex object

Tags: javascript

I'm interested in how you guys lay out your Javascript objects/classes when they contain lots of functions, all of which need to be on the same 'level' (i.e. they need to remain as first level functions of the object).

So with a structure like this...

```
Namespace.class = {
    abc: 1,
    def: 2,
    ghi: 3,

    funcA: function(){
       // Some logic
    },

    funcB: function(){
       // Some logic
    },

    // Lots more functions

    funcN: function(){
       // Some logic
    }  
}
```

This can all get pretty unwieldy.  How do you lay out these types of objects to make them readable, easy to maintain and quick for new developers to pick up?

My approach has been to organise everything in alphabetical order, so you know roughly where to go if you know a function's name.

But does it make more sense to group functions that are closely related in what they do and those that refer to eachother?

Comment: The answer is yes, it does.

Comment: When classes/objects contain so many function that you have trouble finding them, you should split your object/class into multiple objects/classes

Comment: @Borre, sometimes, but not always. Some classes simply have lots of functions.

Comment: I actually agree with @Borre. If you find your classes/objects getting inordinately large, split out some of the functionality. Similar to AngularJS where they recommend taking the logic out of the controllers and putting it into services. The same logic can be applied to vanilla JS as well.

Comment: @adimauro The logic applies to any OO design, it's the S in SOLID: Single Responsibility Principle; one object does one thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many approaches here and it depends on how exactly you interact with your code.

Some things to keep in mind:

**1) If the code is unwieldy, a refactoring is probably overdue.**

Consider breaking your class into smaller classes each dealing with different aspects of what the big class does. Split functionality in multiple namespaces if you use static functions rather than classes.

Consider splitting functionality over multiple files (one-class-per-file for example) and having a build process that combines and minifies your output.

**2) Tools can help.**

If you deal with large codebases it's probably a good idea to find an editor (or learn to use its functions better) that can help you deal with it. Your IDE will probably have some functionality to help you navigate the file structure better, like a file structure overview, or code regions, or objects view

**3) Organize functions by what makes sense.**

An alphabetic solution could make sense in some situations, but grouping by functionality is probably better. Putting exported methods all in one place is probably a good idea as well:

```
Namespace = function() {
  var f1 = function() { };
  var f2 = function() { }; // this is internal

  // Exported methods
  return {
    f1 : f1
  }
}();
```

**4) Document your code.**

While reading the code is invaluable in giving someone an in-depth understanding, code ducmentation is essential in having a first-glance understanding. It can also be useful to you during development because you don't have to remember all the quirks of your code.

**5) Enforce a coding style that can help you.**

Your coding style can help you find things in the code easier. If you always use the same spacing, put braces the same way, etc, finding a function definition can be as easy as `Ctrl-f: myFunc:`.

Comment: I think it will need a refactoring to find some way of splitting it up.  Nevertheless there will be times when a class has a lot of functions - your point about IDE (along with zzzzBov) helped a lot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to modularize the class, and split it across multiple files. Typically this approach is used to provide plugins to a core class. jQuery is a great example of where the class has been extended using plugins.

When you're not interested in splitting the same class across multiple files, I find alphabetizing the function order helps.

In the end the order of the functions shouldn't matter so long as you have a good enough IDE that it lets you jump to the definition for that function.

Comment: Ridiculously, I had no idea that Visual Studio had features of this type in the right-click menu.  +1 for making me realise I know a lot less about my IDE than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

[God objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) are an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) and a good indicator that you have some serious design flaws.

If you follow the [single responsability principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and have a smart IDE that supports intellisense and other similar features, the investment for trying to keep everything ordered is not worth and not necessary since that would be the IDE's job to show all function definitions ordered in a panel for quick-access and to have a global overview.

If you really want to order your functions you could have an automated process that keeps your object literals structured.

However that doesn't mean you shouldn't have any coding standards. I also still organize my code in a way that makes sense e.g. private/public/priviledged members together.